# Git display diff of all unmerged changes in branch

Tags: linux, bash, git

I want to delete some old branches that I have locally, but not before I make sure that the changes in those branches are not changes I want to keep.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that a good way to do that would be to check if it contains anything that has not been added to the master branch yet. So I'd like to display those changes.

Note that I don't want to merely do

```
git diff master..old_branch
```

because I would get a lot of noise, consisting of all the changes that were added to master since then.

I also don't think I want

```
git diff master...old_branch
```

because, from what I undersand, it just displays the commits that were added to old_branch after it derived from master, but does not check if those commits were added (cherry-picked, for instance) to master later on.

How do I do that ?

edit:
Let me try to rephrase my question, since there seems to be some confusion. I don't just want to see commit differences, but rather all lines that have been added by old_branch since it was created from master, but without displaying those that have since been added on the master branch.

So for example:

- master initially contains 'abc'
- old_branch is created from master
- old_branch changes the contents to 'abcdef' (added d,e,f)
- Meanwhile master changes the contents to 'abcdg' (added d,g)

In this case I would want to show the 'ef', since 'def' was added by old_branch, but 'd' was also added in the master branch, and 'g' has been added only by the master branch, so the changes that are in old_branch and not merged in master is 'ef'.

edit2: To put it in yet another perspective:

Let's name `D` the commit where `master` and `old_branch` diverged (ie their common root, or ie where the `old_branch` was created)

Then I want `diff(old_branch, D) - diff(master, D)`

which means that I want all differences between `old_branch` and `D`, but I want to disgard all changes that differ from `old_branch` to `D` if they also differ from `master` to `D`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see any changes in branch `old_branch` that are not currently in `master` your first command is almost correct:

```
git diff old_branch..master
```

Note the two dots vs. three. Also note `old_branch` comes first in the statement. If you reverse the order, you'll get a reverse diff of changes in `master` not in `old_branch`.

Comment: I don't just want to see commits, sorry for using that word in my question, I'll edit it. I want to see any and all (line) differences that were "added" by that branch, compared to the master branch.

Comment: I have made the edit. I also added an example, it's not really written in a git manner but I hope you'll understand the analogy.

Comment: Also the edit you made to my question, changing 'diff' to 'log', did not represent my question. I do want to see line differences, with diff, not just list commits. I changed it back to the way it was.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to my question

Comment: @Vivi See my edits and let me know if that answers your question now

Comment: Thanks for the edit. No it doesn't answer my question, the command you suggest is already part of my original question, and I state there why it's not what I want: using this command, I also get a diff of changes that were added to master since they diverged. Please look at the example I added which portrays what I want to achieve, and tell me if you understand it.

Comment: I added a second edit, which words my question yet another different way, hoping you will understand it better this time.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to my question

Comment: Did you forget me ?